# How do I load all variables to localStorage every x seconds to remove clutter?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I would like to use the setInterval function to load all the variables to localStorage every x seconds, and then when the user reloads the page the contents are the same as the last save. For example, how would I do this with the player's name? This is my code so far:

```
if (localStorage.saved) {
  var name = "Unnamed Player";
} else {
  name = localStorage.name;
}

setInterval(function() {
  saveData();
},60000);

function saveData() {
  localStorage.name = name;
  localStorage.saved = 1;
}
```

I tried using all localStorage variables but math became difficult with the Number() function and it was hard for me to read. I also tried moving the `name = localStorage.name;` code to different places so it runs every time the page reloads.

Comment: That's not how you access local storage. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.

Comment: LocalStorage is a synchone API in other terms it have performance issue to play with it intervally

Answer (score 0):

[Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is accessed using the methods `.getItem()` and `.setItem()` and it only stores and returns strings.

Storing an item

```
localStorage.setItem('name', name);
localStorage.setItem('saved', '1');
```

Getting an item

```
let saved = localStorage.getItem('saved');
// and then to continue your example
if (saved === '1') {
  ...
```